How to save images from a bricked Samsung tablet with MDM
My sister has a Samsung Tab A7 Lite that is soft bricked - stops loading at the logo.
Unfortunately she has many GB of photos on this device with huge sentimental value that haven't been backed up anywhere at all.
I can access recovery mode and download mode, and have a copy of the stock ROM from SamMobile, however I cannot flash it.
Trying to sideload from recovery it says "unauthorized".
Trying to install with ODIN it can't because MDM mode is blocking downloads.
MDM mode probably comes from the internet filter that was on it.
Is there any way to access and save these photos? We don't care if the apps and everything else is gone.
A local repair shop told us the only solution is a complete wipe and they couldn't save the photos. Posting here as a last hope!

only way to recover data is to fix the boot-loop. you could start with mtkclient and dump some data. maybe partial bootloader unlock and booting modified boot.img is possible. with adb enabled in boot.img you could get a logcat and inject some root commands. if device boots to a stage where data is decrypted you could use that script for reading files of boot-looping device
